# Dropdown for filter, add new item in list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Have dropdown list, which elements are defined in controller

```
ViewBag.AudienceFilter= new SelectList(db.Requests, "Id", "Audience");
```

and this dropdown on view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("AudienceFilter", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

this how the result looks like http://snag.gy/dkuGH.jpg

need this to make a filter, and i need one more item in dropdown: "All", what and where do i need to edit, to add this item?

Comment: Fix the English in your question please, your question is not legible.

Comment: So there isn't quite enough information here to help, and it doesn't appear you've really tried either of your needs. First, what are you "filtering"? What does that even mean - literally? Second, when you say you need "All" - do you really need "All" or do you just need a label of "All" for an empty value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the item to your `SelectList` just do:

```
List<SelectListItem> list = new SelectList(db.Requests, "Id", "Audience").ToList();

var listItem = new SelectListItem();
listItem.Text = "All";
listItem.Value = "All";

list.Add(listItem);

ViewBag.AudienceFilter = new SelectList(list);
```

I'll add the other half of the answer when you clarify what you want.